# Trying to access the other side of a ForeignKey in the django admin display

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

I'm working off the django tutorial, and I was trying to figure out how to call the other side of a ForeignKey. My models right now are just Question and Choice, and under class Choice right now I have:

`question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="choice", on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

(the only change I made from the tutorial was adding related_name)

Then when creating class QuestionAdmin, I added "choice" to list_display, hoping to show choice for a question.

`list_display = ["question_text", "choice", "pub_date", "was_published_recently"]`

In the tutorial, they do something with another class and "inlines" but I'm trying to keep this simple, and I was hoping I could just treat the related_name as another attribute of the Choice model.

I've tried changing the name, and I get different error messages depending on which admin function I'm using (list_display, fields, etc.) but I'm mostly seeing this: [TypeError at /admin/polls/question/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmDU2.png) Is there a way to just access the choices as a regular attribute? Am I doing something wrong?

PS: Another problem I encountered: when I added the related_name to the question attribute under Choice, it stopped showing me the question choices in /polls/1, even though I changed the statement in views.py to `question.choice.get(...)` instead of `question.choice_set.get(...)`. What's up with that?

PPS: That problem was solved by changing other references to choice_set in the html files in templates which I forgot about.

Answer (score 0):

Say there are two models A and B and A is referenced in B as a `ForeignKey`.

You cannot directly reference that field from B when defining an admin class for A (as this reverse relationship points to the whole B model (more like a record of B) rather than just a single field in B). So you'll have to stick with making the related model an inline.

For the other problem, to fetch all related choices of a question, you could use the `all` queryset method:

```
return question.choices.all()
```

Comment: It doesn't let me refer to just a field in B either, if I try to put `choice.choice_text` or anything like that into `list_display` or `fields`, it still gets upset. Also the other problem I had was just that I didn't change `choice_set` to `choice` in the html templates.